# Which file in C++ Builder contains the programs default settings

Tags: c++builder

I just moved my C++ Builder XE3 to a new machine and I cannot find the file that stores all the default settings for the program. e.g. Debugger fonts and colors, etc.

Comment: What makes you think they are stored in a file?  A lot of settings are stored in the Registry instead. Look in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero` subkeys.

Comment: I thought that because I found the desktop setting files called Default Layout.dst, Classic Undocked.dst, and Debug Layout.dst in the bin directory.   No matter, it took me about 8 hours, but I finally have my familiar environment back.

Comment: @user5108_Dan those are just settings of the windows (size, position) layout of the IDE for each of the view mode. Colors style and stuff is not stored there